# I Need to add comma operator for number when typing and restrict 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add `$123,123.12` comma format and restrict the decimal to two places can anyone please help with `regex`. I have tried like this. I have a input box now when I enter it comes as `1231244` but I need like `$123,123.12` how to make a function to achieve this can you help with the code.

```
<input type="text" value="$0.00" step="0.01"/>
```

Comment: can you explain little more? what is your value to format?

Comment: What code Is this? asp.net or jquery or html code?

Comment: html with js @vvtx

Comment: @RameshRajendran check the question again.I have mentioned hope you understand.

Comment: how to know  where we need to put dot?

Comment: simply type a number it should be in comma format for that need regex function and after dot only two decimal allowed.

Comment: I put my best for you. please take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at this below code:

```
var value ="1231244"
var lasttwovalue = value % 100;
var firstValue= parseInt(value.slice(0,-2))
if(lasttwovalue >50)
{
   lasttwovalue = '00';
   firstValue = firstValue + parseInt(1)
}
console.log('$'+ firstValue.toLocaleString() + '.' + lasttwovalue)

//result is $12,313.00 if value is 1231255
//result is $12,312.44 if value is 1231244
```

Working demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/459t9g29/2/)

Comment: can you please update code related to input tag with demo in fiddle so that it will be easy for me test and accept your answer if it satisfy my requirement

Comment: So I need some details from your side. which field is input field and which one is output field?  I mean where the data coming from and where we will show the output?

Comment: Input tag : you can input in it itself and output also in same input tag